# Internal degrees of freedom of a Weyl spinor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology

In statistical mechanics, we have formulas like
$$
n
=
\frac{g}{2\pi^2}
\int_m^\infty
\frac{E(E^2 - m^2)^{1/2}}{e^{(E - \mu)/T} \pm 1}\ dE
.
$$
where $g$ is the internal degrees of freedom. What is the value of $g$ for a Weyl spinor?
For context, I am looking at the first part of eq. (6) in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.42.3344). For the charge, we can write more explicitly
$$
Q
=
3 \cdot N \cdot \frac{2}{3}
(\mu_{\rm uL} + \mu_{\rm uR})
+
3 \cdot N \cdot
\left(
-\frac{1}{3}
\right)
(\mu_{\rm dL} + \mu_{\rm dR})
+
(-1)\cdot
\sum_i(\mu_{iL} + \mu_{iR})
- 2\cdot 2 \mu_W - 2m\mu_-
$$
The factor of 3 on the quark chemical potentials is due to color, $N$ is the number of generations and the fractional powers are their charge. The bosons $W$ and $\phi^-$ get an extra factor of two since they are bosons (there are $m$ Higgs doublets in this paper). However, the additional factor of two for $\mu_W$ only makes sense if the leptons have $g = 1$ and the W boson has $g = 2$ (before electroweak symmetry breaking).

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you include that formula for $Q$ and a paragraph on W bosons? Isn't your question about the statistical mechanics of Weyl fermions?